# How i can modernize deprecated FSPathMakeRef, FSIsAliasFile, FSResolveAliasFileWithMountFlags, FSRefMakePath

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager, macos-carbon

I need help to silent Deprecated: `FSPathMakeRef`, `FSIsAliasFile`,
`FSResolveAliasFileWithMountFlags`, `FSRefMakePath`.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

// 1)  deprecated FSPathMakeRef **//

```
    error = FSPathMakeRef((UInt8*)[filename fileSystemRepresentation], &ref, &isFolder);
    if (error) return NO;
```

// 2) here deprecated FSIsAliasFile ***//

```
    error = FSIsAliasFile(&ref, &isAlias, &isFolder);
    if (error) return NO;

    if (isAlias)
    {
        if (isFolder) return YES;
```

// 3) here deprecated FSResolveAliasFileWithMountFlags ***//

```
        error = FSResolveAliasFileWithMountFlags(&ref, true, &isFolder, &isAlias,
                                                 kARMMountVol | kARMNoUI | kARMMultVols | kARMSearch);
        if (error) return NO;
        if (isFolder) return YES;
```

// 4) here deprecated CFURLCreateFromFSRef ***//

```
        fileURL = CFURLCreateFromFSRef(kCFAllocatorDefault, &ref);
        filepath = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(fileURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle));
        CFRelease(fileURL);
```

Answer (score 3):

The modern approach is to use `NSURL`s to represent file locations. So, you're going to have to replace all uses of `FSRef`.  (That is, if you were hoping to replace `FSPathMakeRef()` with a different function that also gives you an `FSRef`, you will be disappointed.)

So, instead of `FSPathMakeRef()`, you use `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` or `+alloc` plus `-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]`.

To replace `FSIsAliasFile()`, you would use `-[NSWorkspace typeOfFile:error:]` to get the type and then `-[NSWorkspace type:conformsToType:]` to check it against `kUTTypeAliasFile`.

To replace `FSResolveAliasFileWithMountFlags()`, you use the "bookmark data" functionality of `NSURL`.  First use `+bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:error:` to get the bookmark data from the file, then use `+URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeToURL:bookmarkDataIsStale:error:` to resolve it.

You won't need a replacement for `CFURLCreateFromFSRef()` because you will already have an `NSURL`.

Comment: Thank You Ken!!! I will modify the code according to your approach. If I meet the problems I hope to count on your help. Special thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The problem is that FSIsAliasFile() is 3.7 faster thantypeOfFile:error:] plus

Comment: @Leonardo, you can try `-[NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error:
]` with key `NSURLIsAliasFileKey`. That may be faster than the UTI approach. Also, are you doing this at such a frequency that the speed is significant?

Comment: Thanks. But NSURLIsAliasFileKey returns YES either for aliases and symLinks. Even FSIsAliasFile returns YES for aliases and symLinks. The only way I know to get YES for an alias and NO for a symLink is to use: NSString    *type = [workspace typeOfFile:self error:nil];
    return [type isEqualToString:@"com.apple.alias-file"]; But this method is very slow. I'm looking for something using lstat. Somebody knows?

Comment: @Leonardo: Well, you can check `NSURLIsSymbolicLinkKey` first before checking `NSURLIsAliasFileKey`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FSIsAliasFile() is still 3.7 faster than

```
NSString    *type = [workspace typeOfFile:filePath error:nil];
return [type isEqualToString:@"com.apple.alias-file"];
```

Me too, I would like to replace the obsolete FSIsAliasFile() API, but with million of files to scan, this is going to be a pain. Do you know a faster way?